Spark - Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration
I am testing a spark application locally, when it writes to GCS bucket I get the below error.
Error:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:250)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:58)

Versions:

Spark - 3.3.2
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-api:jar:3.3.2
Java 8
macOS 14.7

I've tried adding the below config,
("fs.gs.impl","com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
and
"com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:jar:3.0.0" dependency, but the issue could not be resolved. Kindly help.

How did you add that JAR file? Also, Java 8 is end of life. Use 11 for Hadoop + Spark
